# What do optimal tours tell about finite point sets?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, combinatorial-optimization

Let $T_{\mathrm{MIN}}$ and $T_{\mathrm{MAX}}$ denote the shortest, resp. longest Hamilton cycle through a set of $n=2k+1$ points.

Let further $S_{\mathrm{MIN}}$ and $S_{\mathrm{MAX}}$ be the "antipodal" Hamilton cycles related to $T_{\mathrm{MIN}}$ and $T_{\mathrm{MAX}}$.

If $\left(\pi(1),\,\dots,\,\pi(n=2k+1)\right)$ is the order in which the points are encountered on a Hamilton cycle, then $\left(\pi'(1),\,\dots,\,\pi'(n\right)$ with $\pi'(i)=\pi(i+(i-1)*k)$ is the order in which they are encountered on the related *antipodal* Hamilton cycle with additions modulo $n$.

**Questions:**

- what does $\frac{\left(\left|T_{\mathrm{MIN}}\right|-\left|S_{\mathrm{MIN}}\right|\right)\ +\ \left(\left|T_{\mathrm{MAX}}\right|-\left|S_{\mathrm{MAX}}\right|\right) }{2}$ tell about the point set given that the measure becomes 0 for regular $(2k+1)$-gons?
- what is the maximal value of the measure, say depending for points from Euclidean spaces, depending on dimension and distance measure?

Comment: @SamHopkins thank you for pointing me to the error; Ihave edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @SamHopkins no, you start at the first point on the "original" tour and then move ahead $k$ tour edges to get the next point on the antipodal tour, or put differently $\pi'(i)=\pi(i+(i-1)*k)$